# Spring Batch datasource settings changes the behavior of the application transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, datasource

In my Spring Boot application I have a JNDI datasource configured like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jndi-name: java:/users
```

After the introduction of Spring Batch the behavior of some REST services has changed.

For example, previously a service had this log:

```
2022-05-19 12:56:27.348 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2022-05-19 12:56:27.349 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(281567772<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-05-19 12:56:27.349 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.UserService.createDelegation]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2022-05-19 12:56:27.349 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@7bac569f]
2022-05-19 12:56:27.349 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.UserService.createDelegation]
2022-05-19 12:56:27.358 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(281567772<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-05-19 12:56:27.358 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2022-05-19 12:56:27.358 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
2022-05-19 12:56:27.361 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
2022-05-19 12:56:27.432 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.countAllBystate]: This method is not transactional.
2022-05-19 12:56:27.437 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByUser]: This method is not transactional.
2022-05-19 12:56:27.442 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByFiscalnumber]: This method is not transactional.
2022-05-19 12:56:27.446 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(281567772<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-05-19 12:56:27.446 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.SystemService.getKey]
2022-05-19 12:56:27.447 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1976763709<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-05-19 12:56:27.531 DEBUG 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@67f4dd10]
2022-05-19 12:56:27.531 TRACE 667690 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.SystemService.getKey]
```

now the same service has this other log:

```
2022-05-19 10:15:52.150 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2022-05-19 10:15:52.150 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Creating new transaction with name [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.UserService.createDelegation]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2022-05-19 10:15:52.150 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Acquired Connection [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@2e37bdd7] for JDBC transaction
2022-05-19 10:15:52.150 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Switching JDBC Connection [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@2e37bdd7] to manual commit
2022-05-19 10:15:52.150 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.UserService.createDelegation]
2022-05-19 10:15:52.157 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Participating in existing transaction
2022-05-19 10:15:52.157 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
2022-05-19 10:15:52.157 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] r$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler : Starting resource-local transaction on application-managed EntityManager [SessionImpl(184588778<open>)]
2022-05-19 10:15:52.157 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] r$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler : Joined local transaction
2022-05-19 10:15:52.160 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
2022-05-19 10:15:52.213 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.countAllBystate]: This method is not transactional.
2022-05-19 10:15:52.217 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByUser]: This method is not transactional.
2022-05-19 10:15:52.220 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByFiscalnumber]: This method is not transactional.
2022-05-19 10:15:52.224 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.SystemService.getKey]
2022-05-19 10:15:52.300 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Acquired Connection [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@6cd14b57] for JDBC transaction
2022-05-19 10:15:52.300 DEBUG 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Switching JDBC Connection [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@6cd14b57] to manual commit
2022-05-19 10:15:52.300 TRACE 661470 --- [default task-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [it.ipzs.sgdd.service.SystemService.getKey]
```

Please, note the use of **DataSourceTransactionManager** instead of **JpaTransactionManager**.

I believe the different behavior is due to the following configuration, but I don't know how to do it without changing the behavior in the rest of the application:

```
@Bean
    BatchConfigurer myBatchConfigurer(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                      ExecutionContextSerializer executionContextSerializer,
                                      PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
            @Override
            protected JobExplorer createJobExplorer() throws Exception {
                JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
                jobExplorerFactoryBean
                        .setSerializer(executionContextSerializer);
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
                return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
            }

            @Override
            protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
                JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean
                        .setSerializer(executionContextSerializer);
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
                return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: This is because by default, when using `@EnableBatchProcessing`, Spring Batch will register a `DataSourceTransactionManager` when you provide a data source bean in your application context. You need to make sure to use a `JpaTransactionManager` in your `BatchConfigurer`.

Answer (score 0):

More than a solution, I found a workaround.
Since only serialization was needed, I deleted the BatchConfigurer and added the following annotation to the DTOs:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
```